# .htaccess not being read

Tags: .htaccess

Iam trying to redirect my home page or any other page on the site to a particular php page . 
This is my htaccess

```
Redirect 301 http://test.com/info http://test.com/get_forms_data.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^test.php$ http://test.com/get_forms_data.php [R=301,L]
```

I have checked my apache server .rewrite is enabled .

It still doesnt work .

Comment: Does the file have the right permissions?

Comment: Do you get an error when you deliberately introduce a mistake into the file? (To see whether it gets parsed at all)

Comment: @Viehzeug - yes i have given the right permissions.

Comment: @Pekka -  No i dont , NO MATTER WHAT GARBAGE I TYPE INTO MY HTACCESS file .Could u tell me the possible reasons behind this .

Comment: Check out `AllowOverride` in your server config: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

Comment: not sure what to check in that..

Comment: allowOverride is set to ALL now , was none before

Comment: nope..server is not reading my htaccess at all i believe.

Comment: hey got it working...had to restart the apache after the changes done.

Answer (score 29):

If no matter what you put into your `.htaccess` file, you don't even get an error, that means that you probably **need to have**

`AllowOverride All`

set in your site configuration.

If you're on ubuntu, the place to look for the configuration is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. There you should find a file called `default` if this is a stock install of the default **LAMP** stack (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

The key part there is this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. After that don't forget to restart your apache like so:

```
$ service apache2 restart
```

Comment: to me is a different problem

Answer (score 10):

As an addition to Morgan's answer, putting `AllowOverride All` in your virtual host is sometimes not enough. I had this in my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Directory />
   ...
   AllowOverride All
   ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You would expect this to work, wouldn't you, `<Directory />` means it should be applied to everywhere on the file system. But `.htaccess` was still being ignored. Restarting the server did not help. I put junk in the .htaccess file to confirm it was not being read.

My mistake was assuming a virtual host overrides the global configuration.  Kind of it does: my above configuration overrides any global settings for the `/` directory. But the global configuration overrides it back for `/var/www/` and below. My fix is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <Directory /var/www>
   ...
   AllowOverride All
   ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(this assumes none of the other configuration needed to apply outside `/var/www`; if it does, make a separate `<Directory />` block for just that special configuration.)

Comment: Been banging my head for 2 days, your answer saved me from tears

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same problem, and Darren Cook's answer gave me the definitive clue to find the solution.

My app was in some folder out of th public `www` path, lt's say in `/opt/my_app`.
I couldn't create a `VirtualHost`, so I created a symlink in Apache's public `www` ponting to my folder:

`/var/www/html/my_app -> /opt/my_app`

The thing is, in my App's Apache config file, I was specifying:

```
<Directory /opt/my_app>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And my `.htaccess` file wasn't being read. Then I saw that in Apache's configuration there was this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Then I realised that **Apache config files do not care about symlinks**, and therefore the general rule was being applied to my App's foler. I changed `Directory` to:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/my_app>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming /var/www/html is the working directory:
Change from AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If Redirection doesn't work inspite of updating apache2.conf

According to the accepted answer, I updated `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in the **apache2.conf** file, however **redirection** via .htaccess file was still **not working** for me!

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All   # did not work inspite of setting to "All"
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

#### What worked for me...

I had to also **enable module redirection**

```
// enable module redirection
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Of course, do not to forget to restart your apache server for the changes to take effect

**[Reference](https://digitalfortress.tech/bugfix/fix-htaccess-not-being-read/)**